# Where can I get a list of DNS entries for a domain name?

Tags: domains, nameserver, mx

What is a site that I can go to get a list of all the DNS entries for a specific domain name? Say I wanted to see what the MX, NS, and whatever else is associated to the domain name?

Comment: Sorry but these type of questions attract far to much spam and are also considered opinionated which service to use, with this said Williams David Edwards has left a you an answer which answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tools available for this. Just to name a few:

- http://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx
- http://viewdns.info/dnsrecord/
- http://viewdns.info/
- http://www.dnswatch.info/
- https://www.ultratools.com/tools/dnsLookup
- http://dns-record-viewer.online-domain-tools.com/

If you want to do this on the command line, try using `dig`. Example command:

`dig google.com`

For more information please refer to [this article](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442431-check-your-dns-records-with-dig).